F12 no longer run dev tools in Firefox
In Firefox (version 126.0), F12 no longer launch dev tools.
In the hamburger menu, More Tools, i only have "Task Manager" and "Page source".
I've tried repairing the install, full uninstall/install, tried to install a portable apps, all ends up with the same behaviour.
F12 still works in chrome, so it's not the keyboard.
A coworker have the same problem.
How can I have dev tools ?

Try Ctrl + Shift + I; I wasn’t able to reproduce the behavior you described

I've found out the issue.
In about:policies, DisableDeveloperTools was set to true.
Setting it to false via Regedit solved the problem.
The key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox\DisableDeveloperTools.

That is specious; it has nothing to do with updating to v. 126.

I had the same issue. The way I around this was first by:

Pressing Ctrl + Shift + I to launch Dev tools
Clicking the 3 dots in the top right to bring up options
Go to Settings
Under Advanced, Toggle "Use the f12 key to open/close dev tools" on and off.

